# Get the multilevel basename of a Path

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I am trying to write a program that is sort of *similar* to UNIX `basename`, except I can control the level of its base.

For example, the program would perform tasks like the following:

```
$PROGRAM /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 1
FILE.txt # returns the first level basename

$PROGRAM /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 2
THE/FILE.txt #returns the second level basename

$ PROGRAM /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 3
TO/THE/FILE.txt #returns the third level base name
```

I was trying to write this in perl, and to quickly test my idea, I used the following command line script to obtain the second level basename, to no avail:

```
$echo "/PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt" | perl -ne '$rev=reverse $_; $rev=~s:((.*?/){2}).*:$2:; print scalar reverse $rev'
/THE
```

As you can see, it's only printing out the directory name and not the rest.
I feel this has to do with nongreedy matching with quantifier or what not, but my knowledge lacks in that area.

If there is more efficient way to do this in bash, please advise

Comment: Avoid the regex, split on `/` and glue back together as many pieces as requested.  (By the by, I would advise to make the number your first argument, or perhaps make it an option with a simple default, such as 1.)

Comment: Take a look at Path::Class::Dir or Path::Class::File https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class::Dir => Filestructure as Object, maybe it will fit your needs. If not, maybe you can explain your need a little bit more... Splitting Paths with '/' or regexp is not helpful in my opinion. The mentioned modules are plattform independent.  Splitting with '/' isn't.

Comment: @tripleee note on some shells scripts its common when `/` is doubled e.g. `/usr/local/etc//confing.conf

Comment: Why bother when [all your base are belong to us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) ? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find that your own solution works fine if you use `$1` in the substitution instead of `$2`. The captures are numbered in the order that their opening parentheses appear within the regex, and you want to retain the outermost capture. However the code is less than elegant.

The [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module is ideal for this purpose. It has been a core module with every release of Perl v5 and so shouldn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my @path = File::Spec->splitdir($ARGV[0]);
print File::Spec->catdir(splice @path, -$ARGV[1]), "\n";
```

**output**

```
E:\Perl\source>bnamen.pl /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 1
FILE.txt

E:\Perl\source>bnamen.pl /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 2
THE\FILE.txt

E:\Perl\source>bnamen.pl /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 3
TO\THE\FILE.txt
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a module ;) Better than reinventing the wheel :D

Answer (score 3):

A pure bash solution (with no checking of the number of arguments and all that):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=/ read -a a <<< "$1"
IFS=/ scratch="${a[*]:${#a[@]}-$2}"
echo "$scratch"
```

Done.

Works like this:

```
$ ./program /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 1
FILE.txt
$ ./program /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 2
THE/FILE.txt
$ ./program /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 3
TO/THE/FILE.txt
$ ./program /PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt 4
PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly what the OP asked for. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Very nice, +1 for the array element manipulation I had no idea about. :-)

Comment: I like it. Extra points if you add file extension as 1, and handle files with no dot in the name. Ready... Go! :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                    

[ $# -ne 2 ] && exit

input=$1
rdepth=$2
delim=/

[ $rdepth -lt 1 ] && echo "depth must be greater than zero" && exit

parts=$(echo -n $input | sed "s,[^$delim],,g" | wc -m)
[ $parts -lt 1 ] && echo "invalid path" && exit

[ $rdepth -gt $parts ] && echo "input has only $parts part(s)" && exit

depth=$((parts-rdepth+2))

echo $input | cut -d "$delim" -f$depth-
```

Usage:

```
$ ./level.sh /tmp/foo/bar 2
foo/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script to do it with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

level=$1
awk -v lvl=$level 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}
    {count=NF-lvl+1;
    if (count < 1) {
        count=1;
    }
    while (count <= NF) {
        if (count > NF-lvl+1 ) {
            printf "%s", OFS;
        }
        printf "%s", $(count);
        count+=1;
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

To use it, do:

```
$ ./script_name num_args input_file
```

For example, if file `input` contains the line "`/PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt`"

```
$ ./get_lvl_name 2 < input
THE/FILE.txt
$
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tripleee said, split on the path delimiter ("/" for Unix-like) and then paste back together.  For example:

```
echo "/PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift} @p = split /\//; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join("/",@p[$start..$#p])' 1
FILE.txt

echo "/PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift} @p = split /\//; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join("/",@p[$start..$#p])' 3
TO/THE/FILE.txt
```

Just for fun, here's one that will work on Unix and Windows (and any other) path types, if you provide the delimiter as the second argument:

```
# Unix-like
echo "PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift;$d=shift} @p = split /\Q$d\E/; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join($d,@p[$start..$#p])' 3 /
TO/THE/FILE.txt
# Wrong delimiter
echo "PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift;$d=shift} @p = split /\Q$d\E/; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join($d,@p[$start..$#p])' 3 \\
PATH/TO/THE/FILE.txt
# Windows
echo "C:\Users\Name\Documents\document.doc" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift;$d=shift} @p = split /\Q$d\E/; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join($d,@p[$start..$#p])' 3 \\
Name\Documents\document.doc
# Wrong delimiter
echo "C:\Users\Name\Documents\document.doc" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift;$d=shift} @p = split /\Q$d\E/; $start=($#p-$n+1<0?0:$#p-$n+1); print join($d,@p[$start..$#p])' 3 /
C:\Users\Name\Documents\document.doc
```